# Teradata - Date format-update query issues

Tags: date, teradata

There are two date columns in Teradata table with following definition.

```
Date1 DATE FORMAT 'DD-MM-YYYY'
Date2 DATE FORMAT 'DD-MM-YYYY'
```

As you can see, the format of the date is same for both the columns.

The values I see in Teradata SQL Assistant are different for Date1 & Date2 ...

```
For Date1 it is shows as MM/DD/YYYY 
For Date2 it is shown as DD/MM/YYYY
```

Also, due to this, `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date...)` is not working same for both the columns.

**Please note:** `Date2` column is updated by me with values like '04-28-2016' i.e. 'MM-DD-YYYY'. And this is to acheive the Date1 format as shown in `SQL Assistant`.

Can you please let me know where I made a mistake ?
Any advise would be helpful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FORMAT` is used for casting from/to a string, but SQL Assistant uses the format specified under *Tools -> Options -> Data Format -> Display dates in this format*. And a `DATE` is stored in an internal format, thus `EXTRACT` is independent of the it.

Btw, the only recommended way to write a date is Standard SQL's `DATE '2016-04-28'`

Comment: Thank you dnoeth. You mean FORMAT is not required at defining table ? in DDL ? How teradata knows which is a date & which is a month ? In my case EXTRACT was behaving differently. Any idea ?

Comment: @Aditya: There's always a FORMAT for a column, if you don't specify in CREATE TABLE it uses the system's default (and then it's not shown by SHOW TABLE). Can you show exact details for the issues with EXTRACT?

Comment: sorry for late reply ... how to figure out where i went wrong in case if my EXTRACT(Month FROM Date) is returning date whereas EXTRACT(Date FROM Date) is returning month. This issue i was facing & not able to understand why ? I hope, my concern bit clear now ?

Comment: @Aditya: `EXTRACT` always extracts a part of a date as a numeric value, `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM col)` returns an INTEGER. Only if the data type of that column is not a `DATE` there might be an automatic typecast which is based on the default date format. Can you show what exactly went wrong?

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth. I think the data type was the issue. I reloaded tables so couldnt be able the replicate issue.